# fasterxml.jackson.databind Invalid Definition Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do a post request using a URL which I've defined as the endpoint.

Controller Code:

```
 import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.abc.datacollection.Constants;
import com.abc.datacollection.dao.UserClickDataRepository;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickProjection;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickProjection2;

@Controller    
@RequestMapping(path="/user_click_data") 
public class UserClickDataController {
    @Autowired 
    private UserClickDataRepository userClickDataRepository;
    /**
     * this method adds user click data records into user_click_data table
     * @param searchHisObj
     * @return
     */
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping(path="/add", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") // Map ONLY POST Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addUserClickDataRecord (@RequestBody List<UserClickData> searchHisObj) {
        userClickDataRepository.saveAll(searchHisObj);
        System.out.println("saved click data:"+searchHisObj);
        return Constants.STATUS_OK;
    }
    /**

 * this method fetches all user click data records from user_click_data table
 * @return
 */
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@GetMapping(path="/all")
public @ResponseBody List<UserClickProjection> getAllUserClickDataRecords() {
    return userClickDataRepository.findAllProjectedBy();
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@GetMapping(path="/allsecond")
public @ResponseBody List<UserClickProjection2> getAllUserClickDataRecords2() {
    return userClickDataRepository.findAllProjectedBy2();
}
```

}

DAO Code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickProjection;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickProjection2;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserProjection;

@JsonDeserialize(as = com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData.class)
public interface UserClickDataRepository extends CrudRepository<UserClickData, Integer> {
    public static final String FIND_QUERY = 
    "select new com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData(user.u_type, COUNT(user.u_type)) from UserClickData user GROUP BY user.u_type ORDER BY COUNT(user.u_type) DESC";
    @Query(value = FIND_QUERY)
    //public List<UserProjection> getAllRequestResponseRecords();
     List<UserClickProjection> findAllProjectedBy();

    public static final String FIND_QUERY_2 = 
            "select new com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData(user.u_type, COUNT(user.u_type), user.sys_updated_on) from UserClickData user GROUP BY user.sys_updated_on ORDER BY sys_updated_on DESC";
            @Query(value = FIND_QUERY_2)
            //public List<UserProjection> getAllRequestResponseRecords();
             List<UserClickProjection2> findAllProjectedBy2();
}
```

Class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;



@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class UserClickData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int sys_id;
    private String u_search_term;
    private String u_index;
    private String u_sysid;
    private String u_table;
    private String u_facet_id;
    private String department;
    private Date sys_updated_on;
    private String u_type;
    private int flag;
    private String u_user;
    private String u_solr_request_response;
    private String u_title;
    private String u_page;
    private String u_portal;

    @Transient
    private long count;

//  public UserClickData(int sys_id, String u_search_term, String u_index, String u_sysid, String u_table, String u_facet_id, String department, Date sys_updated_on, String u_type, int flag, String u_user, String u_solr_request_response, String u_title, String u_page, String u_portal) {
//      this.sys_id = sys_id;
//      this.u_search_term = u_search_term;
//      this.u_index = u_index;
//      this.u_sysid = u_sysid;
//      this.u_table = u_table;
//      this.u_facet_id = u_facet_id;
//      this.department = department;
//      this.sys_updated_on = sys_updated_on;
//      this.u_type = u_type;
//      this.flag = flag;
//      this.u_user = u_user;
//      this.u_solr_request_response = u_solr_request_response;
//      this.u_title = u_title;
//      this.u_page = u_page;
//      this.u_portal = u_portal;
//  }

    public UserClickData(String u_type, long count) {       //, long count
        this.u_type = u_type;
        this.count=count;
    }

    public UserClickData(String u_type, long count, Date sys_updated_on ) {
        this.u_type = u_type;
        this.count=count;
        this.sys_updated_on=sys_updated_on;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count=count;
    }

    public int getSys_id() {
        return sys_id;
    }
    public void setSys_id(int sys_id) {
        this.sys_id = sys_id;
    }
    public String getU_search_term() {
        return u_search_term;
    }
    public void setU_search_term(String u_search_term) {
        this.u_search_term = u_search_term;
    }
    public String getU_index() {
        return u_index;
    }
    public void setU_index(String u_index) {
        this.u_index = u_index;
    }
    public String getU_sysid() {
        return u_sysid;
    }
    public void setU_sysid(String u_sysid) {
        this.u_sysid = u_sysid;
    }
    public String getU_table() {
        return u_table;
    }
    public void setU_table(String u_table) {
        this.u_table = u_table;
    }
    public String getU_facet_id() {
        return u_facet_id;
    }
    public void setU_facet_id(String u_facet_id) {
        this.u_facet_id = u_facet_id;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public Date getSys_updated_on() {
        return sys_updated_on;
    }
    public void setSys_updated_on(Date sys_updated_on) {
        this.sys_updated_on = sys_updated_on;
    }
    public String getU_type() {
        return u_type;
    }
    public void setU_type(String u_type) {
        this.u_type = u_type;
    }
    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
    public void setFlag(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
    public String getU_user() {
        return u_user;
    }
    public void setU_user(String u_user) {
        this.u_user = u_user;
    }
    public String getU_solr_request_response() {
        return u_solr_request_response;
    }
    public void setU_solr_request_response(String u_solr_request_response) {
        this.u_solr_request_response = u_solr_request_response;
    }
    public String getU_title() {
        return u_title;
    }
    public void setU_title(String u_title) {
        this.u_title = u_title;
    }
    public String getU_page() {
        return u_page;
    }
    public void setU_page(String u_page) {
        this.u_page = u_page;
    }
    public String getU_portal() {
        return u_portal;
    }
    public void setU_portal(String u_portal) {
        this.u_portal = u_portal;
    }
}
```

Error Stack:

```
2019-10-16 16:02:29.394 ERROR 9058 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.servicenow.datacollection.entity.UserClickData]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.servicenow.datacollection.entity.UserClickData` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar!/:2.9.9]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:204) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

URL I'm trying to access:  http://127.0.0.1:9000/user_click_data/add

Payload I'm trying to post:

```
[

    {
        "u_search_term":"madrid",
        "u_index":1,
        "u_sysid":"0db06114db4cc8904819fb2439961991",
        "u_table":"",
        "u_facet_id":"",
        "department":"",
        "sys_updated_on":"2019-10-16T10:32:29.108Z",
        "u_type":"METROCOMM",
        "flag":0,
        "u_user":"",
        "u_solr_request_response":"\"madrid\" OR madrid",
        "u_title":"",
        "u_page":"",
        "u_portal":""
    }

]
```

As you can see, I've added @JsonDeserialize annotation which I imported from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward `(no Creators, like default construct, exist)`. Just add default constructor to your `UserClickData ` class.

Comment: Added it. (Commented it out). Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: You have two more non-default constructors below the one you commented out

Comment: The constructor you have commented out is not default constructor. Default constructor takes no parameters. If you create some constructor in your class - default constructor is not generated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Declare a default constructor inside your class.